# How to factorize an equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

How can I quickly factorize an equation without using Ruffini's rule or polynomial division?

Take this equation as an example:

$$x^4-9x^2+20x=0$$

Comment: possible duplicate of [Factoring polynomials to factors involving complex coefficients](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8255/factoring-polynomials-to-factors-involving-complex-coefficients)

Comment: Make the substitution $x^2=\eta$, then you have a quadratic.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy as taking out a certain value from the entire polynomial; in this case, it's $x$. Then you'll have your result of $x(x^3 - 9x + 20)$. In other cases with polynomials of degree 4, you can make the $u = x^2$ substitution, but since there is no constant, you can take the variable out since all the terms share a common factor.

Comment: Be careful.  You factored $x^4 - 9x^2 + 20$, but the problem asked you to factor $x^4 - 9x^2 + 20x$.

Comment: First you factored the wrong polynomial, then the given factorization is incorrect as the constant term multiplies out to $-10$, not $+20$

Comment: Okay, I changed it.